# How to set hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto in Spring with Annotations and pure Java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-annotations, hibernate-annotations

How would one go about setting up the following in Spring using only Java and annotations.

`<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>`

I amIt should be possible and I do believe it is a lot cleaner to make projects xml free.

PS: This shouldn't be important but I'm running this on Heroku.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Added this to the class where the dataSource() is and it fixed my issue.

```
final Properties hibernateProperties() {
    final Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();

    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");

    return hibernateProperties;
}
```

Full example is here https://github.com/arose13/Heroku-Spring-Postgres-Example.

**EDIT PS**: For this line `hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto","update");` check out this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do) to figure out the best value if `update` isn't right for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a ready to use annotation for Java for hbm2ddl out of the box.

Hibernate uses the standard Java Persistance Annotations (JPA) plus some Hibernate extension annotations.

See: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/

Generally I would rather recommend you externalise the setting in a property file rather then hardcoding it in the Java class. Practically auto schema generation is usually something you would only do during test/staging. So you might have different environments with different settings for this.